# tmp_path error after launching from localhost

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I did a Joomla3 project in localhost and I launched the website (hosted to a server) today. After I launch now I can’t install any extensions it gives “Path to Temp Folder” error. In Global configuration >> server I changed the path. But still not installing. What paths should I change after launching the website from localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

check your `configuration.php` under root.

Set the `log_path`  and `tmp_path`

```
public $log_path = '/home/your_path/public_html/logs';
public $tmp_path = '/home/your_path/public_html/tmp';
```

Make sure you're changed the file permission before editing.

Hope its works..

Comment: how to put te path when its hosted already .. link is http://wad.codespark.asia/Joomla_ips

Comment: is it like http://wad.codespark.asia/Joomla_ips/logs and http://wad.codespark.asia/Joomla_ips/tmp ??????

Comment: is that linux hosting , then you will get the path from cpanel, just near the space and bandwidth section